# IndexError when evaluating ndarray with indexes in another ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get values from an ndarray with indices in another ndarray but I keep getting this error

> IndexError too many indices for array.

The array that I'm trying to get the values from, `scores` , has `scores.shape = (10,10000)`
and the array pointing out the indices, `indices` , has `indices.shape = (10000,2)`

I'm trying to get the values this way:

```
values = scores[tuple(indices)]
```

but this is where I get the error.

What I'm trying to do this way is to access several individual values of scores, e.g. `scores[0,6], scores[1,9]` in another array so I get something like

```
[scores[0,6],scores[1,9],...]
```

all in one go and avoiding loops. Those `[[0,6] , [1,9], ...]` are stored in the indices array. I mention the previous in case that could lead to a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following: `scores[indices[:,0],indices[:,1]]`. Or alternatively, `scores[tuple(indices.T)]`.

When you do `scores[tuple(indices)]`, `tuple(indices)` is creating a tuple of 2-element arrays. Numpy interprets this as you trying to get 2 elements of a 10,000 dimensional array! For the sort of indexing you need, Numpy expects arrays of values for each dimension. In other words, rather than `( [x1,y1], [x2,y2] )`, it wants `( [x1,x2], [y1, y2] )`.

Comment: The last line you wrote down illuminated me so much! Thanks @cge ;)